# Problems with c:choose in JSP

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm learning JSP and I'm facing a weird situation that I really don't understand what's happening.

I need to create a simple menu, and I'm receiving as a parameter an identifier of the menu item that refers to the active page, i.e., the menu item that should be shown as a simple text instead of a link, and the code for the menu looks like this:

```jsp
<nav class="application-menu">
    <ul>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${param.activePage eq 'home'}">
                <li>Home</li>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <li><a href="./">Home</a></li>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${param.activePage eq 'search'}">
                <li>Search</li>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <li><a href="search.html">Search</a></li>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

For this example I'm receiving `search` as the `activePage` parameter, but both conditions are being accepted somehow, so the menu that's being shown on the page looks like this:

`Home <a ...>Home</a> Search <a ...>Search</a>`

Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?

Edit 1:
I have already tried to replace

`c:otherwise` by `c:when test="${param.activePage ne 'home'}"`,
and it works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with the missing JSTL directive, as pointed on this question [jstl tag <c:forEach is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45659651/6357780).

When adding the `taglib` for JSTL, it started working correctly.